# How to declare a Vector object in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

im new to learning c++ and iam now in the stage of creating a class that contains a vector of a class object, with methods to add new objects and print them all out.

Here is my code so far:

**BankAccount.h:**

```
#ifndef BANKACCOUNT_H
#define BANKACCOUNT_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class BankAccount
{
    public:
        BankAccount(string C_Name,int C_Balance);
        /*
        void SetCustomerName(string C_Name);
        String GetCustomerName();
        void SetCustomerBalance(int C_Balance);
        int GetCustomerBalance();
        */
        int deposit(int deposit_);
        int withdraw(int withdraw_);
    private:
        string customer_name;
        int customer_balance = 0;
        int Deposit = 0;
        int Withdraw = 0;

};

#endif // BANKACCOUNT_H
```

**BankAccount.cpp:**

```
BankAccount::BankAccount(string C_Name,int C_Balance)
{
    customer_name = C_Name;
    customer_balance = C_Balance;
}


int BankAccount :: deposit(int deposit_){

        Deposit = deposit_;
        Deposit = Deposit + customer_balance;
        cout << "\nDeposit Balance = " << Deposit;
        customer_balance = Deposit;
        return customer_balance;

    }
int BankAccount :: withdraw(int withdraw_){
        Withdraw = withdraw_;
        Withdraw = customer_balance - Withdraw;
        customer_balance = Withdraw;
        cout<<"After Withdraw Balance is "<<customer_balance;
        return customer_balance;
}
```

**Bank.h**

```
#ifndef BANK_H
#define BANK_H
#include <vector>
#include "BankAccount.h"
using namespace std;


class Bank
{
    public:
        //variables , lists
        vector<BankAccount> newAccount;
        BankAccount bk;

        // constructor
        Bank();

};

#endif // BANK_H
```

**Bank.cpp:**

```
#include "Bank.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

Bank :: Bank()
{
    string Customer_name = " ";
    int Customer_balance = 0;

    cout << "Add name please ";
    cin >> Customer_name ;

    cout << "How much balance?";
    cin >> Customer_balance;

 newAccount.push_back(bk(Customer_name,Customer_balance));


}
```

The BankAccount class is fine, the main problem is in the Bank class.

I have created the bank class to create a vectors of BankAccount , with methods that adds all the BankAccount and print them all out.

However this error keeps appearing under the constructor of Bank.cpp:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'BankAccount::BankAccount()'
```

It seems that whenever im trying to declare the class object inside the BankAccount vector , the error keeps on occuring.Can someone please explain what am i doing wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not having a `std::vector` of `BankAccounts`. The problem is that your `Bank` class has a data member defined: `BankAccount bk;`  Since you don't have any explicit constructor arguments, it tries to use the default constructor `BankAccount()`.  There is no constructor declared, so you get a compilation error.

I suspect that you don't actually need that `bk` data member and should probably just remove it.

The next issue is when you try to `push_back` you are calling the `bk` object instead of constructing an object.  What you want is to just have

```
newAccount.push_back(BankAccount(Customer_name,Customer_balance));
```

If you're using `C++11` or greater (which it looks like you are) you can use `emplace_back` instead

```
newAccount.emplace_back(Customer_name,Customer_balance);
```

This would leave your Bank Account class as follows:

```
class Bank {
  public:
    std::vector<BankAccount> newAccount;
    Bank();
};

Bank::Bank() {
    std::string Customer_name = " ";
    int Customer_balance = 0;

    std::cout << "Add name please ";
    std::cin >> Customer_name ;

    std::cout << "How much balance?";
    std::cin >> Customer_balance;

   newAccount.emplace_back(Customer_name,Customer_balance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to implement the constructor of your `BankAccount` class.

```
BankAccount::BankAccount(string C_Name,int C_Balance)
    : customer_name(C_name)
    , customer_balance(C_Balance)
{
    // TODO;
}
```

As a side note, you probably want you input parameter `C_name` to be a `const std::string& cName` (using camelCase to be coherent, so a variable should never start with a capital letter, it's only used for Classes and Structs).

Usually, we use `variable_` for private members (you did the opposite).
Another tip, variables should be initialized out of the body of the constructor.

EDIT:

```
// This is wrong
newAccount.push_back(bk(Customer_name,Customer_balance));
```

It should be:

```
// Construct a valid BankAccount object using it's constructor to fill the vector
newAccount.push_back(BankAccount(Customer_name, Customer_balance));
```

The variable `bk` is useless and needs a default constructor `BankAccount::BankAccount()` hence the error.

Comment: Ooops i forgot to paste that in ,thank you for spotting that however im still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no standard constructor `BankAccount::BankAccount()` defined in your BankAccount.h.

But when you declare the standard constructor then you run in the following error

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall BankAccount::BankAccount(void)" (??0BankAccount@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall Bank::Bank(void)" (??0Bank@@QAE@XZ)   [...]

Means that the member variable `Bank::bk` is declared but never defined.

So to compile your code successfuly I recommend to remove the declaration of the member variable `bk`  in the class `Bank`. It makes no sense. Then do the following in your Bank class.

```
Bank::Bank()
{
   string Customer_name = " ";
   int Customer_balance = 0;

   cout << "Add name please ";
   cin >> Customer_name;

   cout << "How much balance?";
   cin >> Customer_balance;

   BankAccount bankAccount(Customer_name, Customer_balance);
   newAccount.push_back(bankAccount);
}
```

You will verify successfuly that the vector `newAccount` get filled with a new BankAccount object.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined a default constructor. When you use `push_back` it will try to default construct the object then copy the one you are passing in. You also default construct the member `bk` in Bank. You have 2 options to fix this problem.

1. Define a default constructor, ie. `BankAccount() {`
2. If you are in c++11 you can use vectors [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) routine. You will need to redesign to remove the `bk` member from Bank.

Answer (score 0):

All objects contained by a class are constructed *before* the body of the constructor. In this case, your `Bank` object directly contains a `BankAccount` object, `bk`, which is constructed before the opening `{` in your `Bank` constructor:

```
Bank :: Bank()
// ... bk is initialized here....
{
```

You *attempt* to give `bk` some arguments later, in the call to `newAccount.push_back`, but it's too late; the `bk` object has been initialized.

To control *how* objects are initialized in a constructor, you must put calls to their constructors in the *initialization list*:

```
Bank :: Bank()
  : bk(Customer_name,Customer_balance)
{
```

... but of course you haven't yet defined `Customer_name` or `Customer_balance`.

So let's back up a bit: *why* are you pushing an account into your `Bank` when you initialize the `Bank`? Why would an account even exist at this point? Why does `Bank` have `bk` as a member? (Why is that one account treated specially, when there's a whole *`vector`* of accounts that are also contained by the `Bank`?) And how are you going to add more accounts later?

So, try this: first, default-initialize the `Bank`:

```
Bank :: Bank() {}
```

...or, in the header (if you're using C++11 or C++14, which you should be):

```
Bank(void) =default;
```

Then, add a method for adding accounts:

```
Bank::addAcount(void)
{
    // ... use stdin/stdout to get `customer_name` and `customer_balance`...
    newAccount.emplace_back(customer_name,customer_balance);
}
```

(Note that you'll need to add `push_back` instead of `emplace_back` if you're not using C++11 or C++14.)